# What is Select 'X'?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce

```
 sSQL.Append(" SELECT 'X' ");
        sSQL.Append(" FROM ProfileInsurancePlanYear ");
        sSQL.Append(" WHERE ProfileID = " + profileid.ToString() + " AND CropYear = " + cropyear.ToString());
```

This was a query that was originally hitting an access back end. I have moved it over to SQLCE and am perplexed about what this query is supposed to do.

The table structure it hits is:

```
ProfileID
InsurancePlanID
CropYear
INsurance_Price
Levels_XML
```

I am assuming this would select something from the Levels_XML column where the profileid and cropyear match?

Does this even work in sqlCE?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This type of query is typically used to see if a row exists.   If a row is found, the query will return a single character, X.   Otherwise, it will be an empty result set...  You could also say

```
 sSQL.Append(" SELECT count(*) ");
 sSQL.Append(" FROM ProfileInsurancePlanYear ");
 sSQL.Append(" WHERE ProfileID = " + profileid.ToString() + 
             " AND CropYear = " + cropyear.ToString());
```

Which will return a result with either 0 or some positive number.    Different approaches both asking the database simply to indicate whether or not any records existing matching the condition.

Comment: COUNT could be expensive and is a poor example. `SELECT 1 WHERE EXISTS (..query here..)` would be better and checks for 0 or 1 rows

Comment: To be completely pedantic, gbn's query will return an empty result set if no rows satisfy the "query here" query and will return a result set with one row if there are one or more rows that satisfy the query.  SQL server is smart enough to stop once it finds a qualifying row and doesn't need to materialize the entire inner query.

Comment: I am not recommending COUNT(*), I agree it is not the best, but I think it is a bit clearer to explain what is being achieved by SELECT 'X'.

Comment: Selecting 'x' is selecting a static string of 'x' if the record exists. Selecting `COUNT`, which uses a function, is more expensive.

Comment: Does this bring any optimization? If so, how ?

Comment: It will bring optimization in that SQL does not need to read any rows, so it will hopefully use only the index, and not need to visit the data table at all

Answer (score 0):

In general, Select 'X' is used with the EXISTS, as the EXISTS predicate does not care about the values in the rows but just if those rows exist.

For example:-

Q.Find employees who have at least one person reporting to them.

```
SELECT last_name, employee_id FROM employee outer WHERE 
EXISTS (SELECT 'X' FROM employee manager_id=outer.employee_id)
```